# Formula result does not display in Numbers for Mac - Intermittent

Tags: catalina, numbers

*[Note: this is not the same issue as the post entitled "Display Blank on Formula Error" so please don't mark this as duplicate for that reason.]*

[Some cells containing formulae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1pUN.png) are not displaying, [but are displaying correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2KOZ.png) when changed to a literal value  instead of a formula.  [There is no conditional formatting on the cell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GBFS.png)  I have checked [fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxp0M.png) and [font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZbLt.png) as well as cell offsets etc.  I have tried cutting and pasting from other cells, and also tried copying and pasting formats.

**Workaround:** Insert a new table.  Copy and paste the content of the old table into the new table.  Then, find all references to the old table and manually replace them with references to the new table.

**Apple Support says:** This is a corrupt table.  After manually
recreating the table I need to manually update all references 
to the table.

Version info: Numbers 10.0(6748) / Catalina 10.15.4

[image: doesn't display result as formula result]
[image: displays result properly when there is a value]
[image: no conditional formating]
[image: no fill]
[image: default font]

Comment: I asked Apple Support if this would be escalated to engineering.  They said as it may be caused by a bad sector or something like that, they do not escalate document corruption issues to engineering. It would be helpful if they put digital signatures or minimally, CRC checks in the document files so that we could be warned when a "bad sector" like this occurs, particularly if we intend to copy a table for reuse.